# converting messy svn repository to git

Tags: git, svn, merge

I am trying to convert a slightly messy svn repository to git. I tried reading some guides and other SO questions, but get a little lost as to what's the best way to follow.

The SVN repository has a top-level folder structure with folders, something like:

```
 |- client
 |- server
 |- website
 |- misc
```

Most of those folders have the 'standard' svn structure: i.e. `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`. Some are just flat folders however.

```
 |- client
    |- trunk
    |- branches
    |- tags
 |- server
    |- trunk
    |- branches
    |- tags
 |- website
 |- misc
```

The branches and tags might have the same name between different folders. For example, both client and server folders might have a branch called `1.0`.

I managed to convert individual folders using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), and it seems to get the history, as well as branches fine. I can manage to create an individual git repository for each folder. However, I'd like to keep everything in *one repository* eventually.

What's the best way to merge those folders (now git repositories) into one, whilst maintaining the branches, tags and history of each folder? Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426163), I seem to lose both the commit history and the branches from the merged-from repository... Or perhaps I'm just missing some important steps or doing something wrong?

Otherwise, maybe using `svn2git` on each folder separately is not the best approach to migrate from svn to git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually opted for the approach on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139427).

Essentially:

- creating a git project for each sub-folder in the svn repository (using svn2git)
- creating a new git repository merging all repositories into
- adding each project (including all branches) as a remote:

  ```
  git remote add alpha <url/path-to-alpha-repo>
  git remote add bravo <url/path-to-bravo-repo>
  git remote add charlie <url/path-to-charlie-repo>
  for r in $(git remote); do
    git config remote.$r.fetch \
    "$(git config remote.$r.fetch | sed -e 's.remotes.heads/all.')"
    git config --add remote.$r.fetch \
    "$(git config remote.$r.fetch | sed -e 's.heads.tags.g')"
    git config remote.$r.tagopt --no-tags
  done
  git remote update
  ```
- pushing the merged-repository to a remote repository (from now on this will be the 'official' repository).

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the svn repository to the following structure *before* converting to Git:

```
- trunk
  |-client
  |-server
  |-website
  `-misc
- branches
  |-client
  |-server
  |-website
  `-misc
- tags
  |-client
  |-server
  |-website
  `-misc
```

To restructure your svn repository, you'll have to `svnadmin dump` the repository to a file, update all paths in that file, and then `svnadmin load` the updated dump file into a new repository.

Have a look at the structure of the dump file - the actual restructuring can be easily done with an editor that supports search/replace. It needs to be binary-safe though since besides the ascii metadata the dump file also contains raw binary data (of binary files in the repository).

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like an interesting approach, but are you aware of any resources/tools to help do this safely? I had a quick look on an svn dump I have and wouldn't really know where to start (let alone deal with issues of merging e.g. two branches with the same name for client and server...)

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/dump-load-format.txt - search for `Node-path` in the dump file. If you performed copy/move operations, `Node-copyfrom-path` might be relevant, too.

Comment: This stuff seems way over my head to be perfectly honest... Doing some regex search/replace on such a massive scale messing around with the svn internal dump format isn't exactly the solution I was hoping for. Thanks for suggesting this direction though!